# Rails best practice when embedding a signup form on every page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have a User model with some validations behind it.

What I'd like to do is have a signup form on every page of the app, even the mostly static ones.

I figured the best way to do this would be through helper methods in `application_helpers.rb`, which works fine, but validations don't seem to work.

I can also serve the form through an iframe, but that seems a bit hacky.

I'm using partials now, but my client side validation (github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) only works on the /new page, not the application page.

What's the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the basic solutions is to use partial. The benefit is: it's built in, it's simple. The downside is: You'll be busy to feed it some session details for proper rendering.

Another solution is to use [Cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) for this kind of case.

Cells works like a lightweight controller which can do anything a controller can do, and it's independent on any controller. One good use case of Cells is shopping cart, and login form is also a good use case in my opinion.

Comment: I'm using partials now, but my client side validation (github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) only works on the /new page, not the application page.

Comment: @JacksonGariety, if using Cells, the solution is to move rendering logic into cell. The rendered cell is not a partial but an independent component.

Comment: how can I get validation working through this partial? Lets say on I'm a static page that's rendering this dynamic partial, how do I get the validation errors?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend extracting the signup form into a shared partial, which you then explicitly could render wherever you want it.

One could render the signup form directly in the layout file (`app/views/layout/application.html.erb`) if the placement is static no matter of what page you're currently on.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but my client side validation (https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) only works on the /new page, not the application page.

Comment: Why is that? client_side_validations doesn't care about what page you're on, right? As long as you require the JavaScript files in the application manifest?

Comment: I figured it out. Wasn't even what I thought it was. My signup form is in a popup and since the popup starts with display: none, client_side_validation was skipping it. Thank for you help though!

Comment: How can I get validation working through this partial? Lets say on I'm a static page that's rendering this dynamic partial, how do I get the validation errors?

Comment: Could you give me some context in the matter. Code would help me visualize your problem.